# change format of string values to numeric in df

Tags: pandas

I have the following df where some values in the df are strings (those with %) while other ones aren't.

```
                          test    overall
Quents Ratio            270.01%  256.02%
Amount sulphur            0.17     0.19
Amount salt                  -    20.89
amount silica             4.29%    6.84%
```

I would like to make all the values numeric given that I would like to carry out some analysis among the 2 columns.

Desired output:

```
                          test    overall
Quents Ratio            270.01   256.02
Amount sulphur            0.17     0.19
Amount salt                  -    20.89
amount silica             4.29     6.84
```

What I have tried is to:

```
def numeric_df(df):
    df_detail=df.loc[['Quents Ratio','amount silica'],:]
    df_detail= df_detail.apply(lambda x:str(x)[:-1])
    return df
```

But returns same initial df.

How could I obtain the desired output?

Comment: do you need replace `-` to `NaN`?

Comment: No I prefer to mantain it

Comment: hmmm, but then values cannot be numeric, because `-` is string.

Comment: Didn't thought about that, was going apply a 'to_numeric' without thinking that '-' could give me further problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), but values contains also `-`, so impossible convert to numeric:

```
 df = df.replace('%', '', regex=True)
```

If need all values numeric and values contains only `-` chars:

```
df = df.replace({'%': '', '^-$':np.nan}, regex=True).astype(float)
print (df)
                  test  overall
Quents Ratio    270.01   256.02
Amount sulphur    0.17     0.19
Amount salt        NaN    20.89
amount silica     4.29     6.84
```

Another solution with [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) - it replace all non numeric to `NaN`s too:

```
df = df.replace('%', '', regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
print (df)
                  test  overall
Quents Ratio    270.01   256.02
Amount sulphur    0.17     0.19
Amount salt        NaN    20.89
amount silica     4.29     6.84
```